# Stop NSRunloop in NSOperate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know is maybe a bad design, but all I want to do is run a `NSTimer` in `NSOperation`, so here is what I done:

```
#import "CountOperate.h"

@interface CountOperate ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
@property(nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) NSInteger repeatSecond;

@end

@implementation CountOperate

- (void)main
{
    self.repeatSecond = 15;

    self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:self.repeatSecond target:self selector:@selector(update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes]; 
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]; 
}

- (void)cancel
{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    [super cancel];
}

- (void)update
{
    NSUInteger myRandom = arc4random_uniform(100);
    self.dateArray[self.myID] = @(myRandom);     
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
                                     withObject:nil
                                  waitUntilDone:NO];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] performSelector:@selector(update) withObject:nil afterDelay:self.repeatSecond];
}
```

The problem here is that I can not stop it immediately, it must wait to be completed after the completion of the interval timer, it's like `NSRunLoop` must run until the next time the timer fires .

In this example, I had wait 15second, so I can see the `NSOperation` has finish its job.